# adjust layout based on frame size

Tags: figma

I am trying to design a prototype for a web page. This web page can be on anything from full screen on a desktop computer to a small cell phone. And so the frame width can vary from 20" wide to 3" wide.

Is there a way in Figma to have it move controls so that on a wide framework it will have:

```
First name: [_____________________________]
```

while on a cell phone size, it will adjust to:

```
First name: 
[________________]
```

In a perfect world, it would both move the editbox to the next line and reduce the editbox to the width of the screen if the editbox was wider than the screen.

And I'd like to have it handle larger cases. Such as wide screen:

```
First name: [_____________________________]  Last name: [_____________________________]
```

Medium screen:

```
Last name: [_____________________________]
First name: [_____________________________]
```

And small screen:

```
First name: 
[_____________________________]
Last name: 
[_____________________________]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resizing one form field, depending on parent container width:**

This is possible in Figma using either [Constraints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHY9cm_2zwU), or [Auto Layout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TyaGpGDFczw) features.

**Dynamic wrapping of form field elements, depending on parent container width:**

You are trying to simulate Responsive Design and/or flex grid layout on Figma, as if it was already a fully implemented web page viewed in a browser. Form field elements will wrap or get displayed next to each other, depending on the width of the page / browser.

Figma doesn't support this yet. You will have to illustrate both layouts, and then instruct the devs to implement the layouts as responsive design modes for the same page.

As a workaround, you can create a Smart Animation of the form fields wrapping / unwrapping as the page width is changing. It's not an interactive prototype, but it communicates the idea of applying your Responsive Design layout for your form fields.